# python script doesn't work but line by line on the console yes

Tags: python, bash

If I type on the python console these three lines:

```
>> import serial 
>> s = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemFD121', 9600)
>> s.write('00001§1\r')
```

Everything works perfectly!
But if i put these three lines inside a script so:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial 
s = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodemFD121', 9600)
s.write('00001§1\r')
```

And I run it from the bash:

```
/Users/francesco/sender.py
```

Doesn't work!
How is possible? Someone can help me?

Comment: You must run it as `python /Users/francesco/sender.py `

Comment: @arunp9294 NO!!!!

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there an error raised when you run it, or is it not running at all?

Comment: you can add a shebang line and make the file executable. The advantage is that you can put it in the system path and you don't have to type the full path to call it.

Answer (score 2):

you can't run python files directly like that. Have you tried:

```
python /Users/francesco/sender.py
```

Comment: But you can run them directly if you `chmod +x` and add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line.

Comment: @cxw That's going to get you in trouble more than it's worth.  It might work on your local machine, but trying to run that in a different environment is going to cause you problems.  Python files aren't meant to be run like that afaik.

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 it works fine in linux, and on windows the file associations system mean that you can run them without python prefix even if there isn't a shebang. But actually the shebang causes issues in python 3 (with `py` wrapper trying to interpret it)

Comment: ^ little gotchas like that are what I mean.  It might work on some environments, but kind of the point of using an interpreted language like python is to minimize the dependencies on the execution environment.  Python files should be treated as text, not executables.

Comment: the script is executed but I not receive the string on the serial device